# Control the height of horizontal subnav

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to control the height of my subnav. As of now I can only do this by increasing or decreaing the font size. They're has to be an easier way.

http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/ufGCI

Comment: Please be more specific in what you are trying to do. What do you mean by "controlling" the height of your subnav? Do you want to make it taller? Shorter? Responsive? Also, post some code into your question; if your codepen disappears, then this question is useless.

Comment: You need to explain what you want exactly. There a lot of way to "control" the height. You can use `height` and `line-height` in CSS. You can also use `padding`: `padding:2em 1em` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I'm using 50px as an example...

```
.subnav ul li a {
  height:50px;
}
```